# how can I set a value repeatedly to a field with auto clicking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, auto, clicking

I tried to write the auto-clicking function on a web page:

```
var button = document.getElementById('send_order_btnSendOrder');
setInterval(function(){button.click()}, 200)
```

it works correctly
, now after each auto clicking i want these values will be located in fileds.

```
document.getElementById('send_order_txtPrice').value = "24030";
document.getElementById('send_order_txtCount').value = "5";
```

I mean setting values after autoclaving repeatedly.
 how should I change my code?

Comment: Please describe your question in a better way. Maybe post some more code examples and describe what problem you're trying to solve. Otherwise I believe no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById('send_order_btnSendOrder').addEventListener('click', function())
```

And then `removeEventListener('click', function())`